# Paste image from clipboard into Keynote

Tags: keynote, copy-paste

I copied an image into the clipboard: but there is no paste option within Keynote. So.. how to do this basic operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general answer is

> "just be sure to paste into an unoccupied area of the Keynote slide"

My issue was that I was trying to paste into an area already occupied by a textbox.  It may not be obvious due to a bunch of blank lines that make the box extend longer than immediately apparent.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you are on the slide by clicking into it. The universal keyboard Command + V should pass your image. If that doesn't work then be sure you actually **have** something copied to the clipboard. 
Alternatively you can easily drag and drop an image onto a slide.

Comment: Sorry you feel this way. Your original question did not state what you had already tried. You stated there is no basic paste in Keynote. Not that you were trying to paste over a text box. Those here in this forum are fellow users just trying to help.